# Used Google Cloud Translation API When return response 403 "Daily Limit Exceeded"

Tags: php, language-translation, google-cloud-platform

The following confirmation is done.

- Credit card is registered
- It does not exceed the upper limit of each threshold of API

So, I was able to run normally until yesterday.
But I will get an error all the time today.

I use "Cloud Translation API Client Libraries",
If there are other points to check, would you please teach me?

```
$translate = new TranslateClient([
    'projectId' => 'xxxxxxx',
]);
$result = $translate->translate('I am playing Dragon Quest 11 ', [
    'source' => 'en',
    'target' => 'ja',
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it myself.

Used to authorized type 'authorized_user'.

Not so match authentication method.

My solution is:

Constructor add option 'keyFilePath' directory.

```
$translate = new TranslateClient([
    'projectId' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'keyFilePath' => env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
]);
```